# Problem with Query with SUM / Group By

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle SQL query with which I want to fectch totals of several amount columns and some descriptive columns. In short I want output like:

```
INDBDebnmbr INInvoicenmbr INOpenAmount
40          10            100
40          14            125
35          20            200
60          21            75
```

My Querystring:

```
SELECT TRIM(A.ACCOUNTNUMBER) AS INDBDebnmbr
     , TRIM(A.VOUCHER) AS INinvoicenmbr
     , A.DATE_ AS INinvoiceDate
     , A.DUEDATE AS INinvoiceDueDate
     , A.TXT AS INDescription
     , A.EXCHANGECODE AS INCurrencyCode
     , subq.AMOUNTMST AS INOriginalamount
     , subq.SETTLEAMOUNTMST AS INpaidAmount
     , subq.OPENAMOUNT AS INOpenAmount
FROM (
            SELECT  DEBTRANS.VOUCHER AS VOUCHER, 
                    SUM(DEBTRANS.AMOUNTMST) AS AMOUNTMST, 
                    SUM(DEBTRANS.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) AS SETTLEAMOUNTMST, 
                    SUM(DEBTRANS.AMOUNTMST - DEBTRANS.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) AS OPENAMOUNT
            FROM XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBTRANS DEBTRANS 
            WHERE DEBTRANS.OPEN = 1 
            AND DEBTRANS.TRANSTYPE <> 9 
            AND (DEBTRANS.AMOUNTMST - DEBTRANS.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) <> 0 
            AND DEBTRANS.DATASET = 'FIK'
            GROUP BY DEBTRANS.VOUCHER
        ) subq, 
       XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBTRANS A 
WHERE subq.VOUCHER = A.VOUCHER 
GROUP BY    A.VOUCHER, 
            A.ACCOUNTNUMBER,
            A.DATE_, 
            A.DUEDATE, 
            A.TXT, 
            A.EXCHANGECODE,
            subq.AMOUNTMST, 
            subq.SETTLEAMOUNTMST, 
            subq.OPENAMOUNT
```

I do however get

```
INDBDEBNMBR   ININVOICENMBR  ININVOICEDATE  ININVOICEDUEDATE INOPENAMOUNT
10            2022903        12-2-2011 0:00 24-2-2011 0:00   110
35            2022903        11-2-2011 0:00 23-2-2011 0:00   110
20            2022903        17-2-2011 0:00 1-3-2011 0:00    110
10            2022903        14-2-2011 0:00 26-2-2011 0:00   110
29211         2022903        14-2-2011 0:00 26-2-2011 0:00   11
```

How do I get the correct SUMS by DEBTRANS.VOUCHER with the descriptive columns?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: Seems like you dont need to group by date, because the date is always unique for some invoice?

Comment: Suggestion: Use JOIN's instead of WHERE, makes your code more readable

Comment: you have several different DUEDATE per voucher, which value (min/max etc. ) or  do you want to retrieve in the output of the query? Or is it  uninteresting  an can be completely omit?

Comment: @niktrs duedate is always the same but since the table (debtrans) has records for settlements too I'm not sure about the _date @mark guk. Let's say I forget about grouping on dates would I still be able to show them next to the invoicenumber or are those two tied together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unnecessarily joining back to the table to get your additional columns.  I'm guessing that the problem is that you aren't repeating the filter conditions for the outer instance of the table.

Does this do what you want?

```
        SELECT  DEBTRANS.VOUCHER AS VOUCHER, 
                SUM(DEBTRANS.AMOUNTMST) AS AMOUNTMST, 
                SUM(DEBTRANS.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) AS SETTLEAMOUNTMST, 
                SUM(DEBTRANS.AMOUNTMST - DEBTRANS.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) AS OPENAMOUNT
                TRIM(DEBTRANS.ACCOUNTNUMBER) AS INDBDebnmbr
              , DEBTRANS.DATE_ AS INinvoiceDate
              , DEBTRANS.DUEDATE AS INinvoiceDueDate
              , DEBTRANS.TXT AS INDescription
              , DEBTRANS.EXCHANGECODE AS INCurrencyCode
        FROM XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBTRANS DEBTRANS 
        WHERE DEBTRANS.OPEN = 1 
        AND DEBTRANS.TRANSTYPE <> 9 
        AND (DEBTRANS.AMOUNTMST - DEBTRANS.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) <> 0 
        AND DEBTRANS.DATASET = 'FIK'
        GROUP BY DEBTRANS.VOUCHER
                ,DEBTRANS.ACCOUNTNUMBER
                ,DEBTRANS.DATE_
                ,DEBTRANS.DUEDATE
                ,DEBTRANS.TXT
                ,DEBTRANS.EXCHANGECODE
```

If not, then presumably one or more of those additional columns does not have a unique value by voucher.  In this case, you need to decide how you want to select which value to display for each group.  You could for example select the maximum value as shown below, but does that make sense for your businesss logic?

```
        SELECT  DEBTRANS.VOUCHER AS VOUCHER, 
                SUM(DEBTRANS.AMOUNTMST) AS AMOUNTMST, 
                SUM(DEBTRANS.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) AS SETTLEAMOUNTMST, 
                SUM(DEBTRANS.AMOUNTMST - DEBTRANS.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) AS OPENAMOUNT
                MAX(TRIM(DEBTRANS.ACCOUNTNUMBER)) AS INDBDebnmbr
              , MAX(DEBTRANS.DATE_) AS INinvoiceDate
              , MAX(DEBTRANS.DUEDATE) AS INinvoiceDueDate
              , MAX(DEBTRANS.TXT) AS INDescription
              , MAX(DEBTRANS.EXCHANGECODE) AS INCurrencyCode
        FROM XAL_SUPERVISOR.DEBTRANS DEBTRANS 
        WHERE DEBTRANS.OPEN = 1 
        AND DEBTRANS.TRANSTYPE <> 9 
        AND (DEBTRANS.AMOUNTMST - DEBTRANS.SETTLEAMOUNTMST) <> 0 
        AND DEBTRANS.DATASET = 'FIK'
        GROUP BY DEBTRANS.VOUCHER
```

Answer (score -1):

In sub query `subq` add another condition in `WHERE` caluse

```
AND DEBTRANS.VOUCHER = A.VOUCHER
```

This means that the voucher of the main query must match the sub query voucher number.

Comment: Thanks Talha but ...DEBTRANS.DATASET = 'FIK' AND DEBTRANS.VOUCHER = A.VOUCHER gives me INVALID COLUMNAME?

Comment: This predicate already exists in the `WHERE` clause of the main query.

Comment: But the inner query does not have this value which is actually calculating the SUM for the same VOUCHERs.